# Is there an equivalent to sysdate-1/24 in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried looking around for this but I can't find an answer that seems to work with the code I'm using. Basically, the below query searches on any result from the current date. I'm trying to make it so it will search only on the last hour.

In oracle I could do this using sysdate-1/24, is there a simple equivalent within SQL server? Bearing in mind I'm already using cast to get the current sysdate.

```
Select  distinct m_record_server
from search_recording_file1
where tr_date_recorded >= cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 110) as datetime)
and m_record_server is not null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
getdate() - 1.0/24
```

SQL Server allows you to use such arithmetic on `datetime`.

The more common way would be:

```
dateadd(hour, -1, getdate())
```

In your query, you do not need to cast to a string at all:

```
Select distinct m_record_server
from search_recording_file1
where tr_date_recorded >= getdate() - 1.0/24 and m_record_server is not null;
```

If you want the *date* that was there one hour ago (which seems to be the intent of the code, if not the rest of the question):

```
Select distinct m_record_server
from search_recording_file1
where tr_date_recorded >= cast(getdate() - 1.0/24 as date) and m_record_server is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in the context of my code, this would be:     `where tr_date_recorded >= cast(convert(varchar(10), getdate() -1.0/24, 110) as datetime)`

Comment: @Tommen absolutely not, please stop converting datetime to varchar. In this case you are trimming off the timepart of getdate().